# Mysql query returns wrong data with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to get data from mysql database and I get wrong data. I want to get all data with the `cart_Status` of 2 or 3 which have the `view_Status` of 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `view_Status` = 1 AND cart_Status = 2 OR `cart_Status` = 3
```

This is how my data structure and table looks like:

[image]

But in result, it returns something regardless of `view_Status = 1` which is not my target.

it returns :

[image]

**Of course, it should not return anything! But, it does!**

Comment: Try this `SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `view_Status` = 1 AND (cart_Status = 2 OR `cart_Status` = 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about operator precendence.
Your query evaluates as

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE (`view_Status` = 1 AND cart_Status = 2) OR `cart_Status` = 3
```

You should to add parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `view_Status` = 1 AND (cart_Status = 2 OR `cart_Status` = 3)
```

Comment: Oops! I forgot that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Called operator precendence in any programming language.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `view_Status` = 1 AND (cart_Status = 2 OR `cart_Status` = 3)
```

or better

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `view_Status` = 1 AND cart_Status in (2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be learning SQL.  Use parentheses in the `WHERE` clause, particularly when you mix `AND` and `OR`.

However, in your case, `IN` is a better solution:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM `cart` c
WHERE c.view_Status = 1 AND cart_Status IN (2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with operators precedence. Typically `AND` is executed before `OR` in programming languages (think of `AND` as of multiplication of bits, and of `OR` as of addition of bits and precedence becomes familiar). So, your condition:

```
`view_Status` = 1 AND cart_Status = 2 OR `cart_Status` = 3
```

is parsed like this:

```
(`view_Status` = 1 AND cart_Status = 2) OR `cart_Status` = 3
```

which results in all rows with specific `cart_Status` to be selected. You have to add parenthesis around the second clause:

```
`view_Status` = 1 AND (cart_Status = 2 OR `cart_Status` = 3)
```

or, even shorter:

```
`view_Status` = 1 AND cart_Status IN (2, 3)
```